# Subtitles won't display from <track> element

Tags: javascript, html5-video, subtitle

I have a video element on my page, and am pulling in the tracks source dynamically to display subtitles.

My track element does appear inside my video element the DOM as such:

```
<video id="content" src="[myvideoURL]">
   <track id="tracks" src="[mysubtitleURL].vtt" label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en-US">
</video>
```

But the subtitles never actually appear.

I also tried to  get them to appear by default with some JS:

```
var trackElement = document.getElementById('tracks');
trackElement.addEventListener('load',function(){
                this.mode = "showing";
 });
```

But haven't had any luck with that.

Is there something else I need to be doing to get these to display??

Comment: Do you have a working sample to show? Are the vtt files on the same domain as your video + html? Are you sure the vtt files are formatted correctly?

Comment: If you have subtitle tracks in your video, and you added the `controls` attribute in your video element, you should see a "CC" icon (it may vary depending on which browser are you using) to activate and deactivate subtitles. Is that icon appearing?